# Symfony not configured with Nginx server

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I am new in PHP Symfony, I am trying configure symfony project with nginx but it is showing nginx 404 error, symfony path URL not working. only index.php file working.

Reference website:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/symfony/

**Here is my nginx code**:-

```
server {

    #listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name dummyurl.com;
    root /var/www/html/folder name;
    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
      try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
   }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
              fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
              fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(\.*)$;
              include fastcgi_params;
              fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
              fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
              internal;
              #fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri?$args=404;
    }


}
```

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: `location` sections should be inside `server` section. Anyway, you can simply copy example config from Symfony docs (https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx) and just change `root` path and `server_name` if you're using some local domain for your project.

Comment: @Jakub Matczak i tried but not working

Comment: It would be far more much easier to help you if you provide real nginx config that you've tried, instead of modified one which you have provided. Anyway, the `root` param's value should point to `public` directory inside Symfony project. I don't think it's `/var/www/html/folder name` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also the screen shows that you're trying to access url `/symfony/web/index.php` which I also don't understand. Symfony 3 used `web` directory, but it didn't have `index.php` file, but `app.php`. Symfony 4 on the other hand uses `index.php`, but the `web` directory has changed into `public`. Which Symfony version do you actually use?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't set te server root to the public directory

```
server {
    root /var/www/project/public;
}
```

Look at the documentation which Kamil Ścisłowski mentioned:
[Offical Web Server Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx)

Comment: your forgot the public part:

Comment: sry forgit to add the code line: root /var/www/html/public

Comment: Try to use the example provided by the official documentation and extend the configuration from there for your needs.